# How do I use the Google Classroom API in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-classroom

I am trying to use the API for Google Classroom from the chrome extension, but I cannot get it to work. It works perfect when following the quickstart example from https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/js. But, when I try to do the same from chrome extension it doesn't work. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What errors do you get? Which part of the code is causing issues?. Check this documentation on how to ask questions in Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I cannot authorize the request from the chrome extension. If you have any example on how to use a Google API from a Chrome extension I would be   grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Google JavaScript API Client directly with Chrome extensions. Try using/adapting the [`gapi-chrome-apps-lib`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/libraries/gapi-chrome-apps-lib) GitHub sample.